# How to plot the derivative of eigenfunctions obtained using NDEigensystem?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I'm using NDEigensystem to get the eigenfunctions for Laplacian operator. After that I want to plot `\frac{1}{funs[[1]]}*\frac{d funs[[1]]}{dx}*funs`vs x where funs is the set of eigenfunctions obtained. Can anyone please tell me how I can do this?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe26

Comment: Can you give the code of what you have tried?